# GridView.DataBind() results in A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

I'm trying to deploy my asp.net web form app on Godaddy .I can connect to the Sql Server and everything goes well,i.e authentication goes well but as soon as the line "gridview1.DataBind()" is being executed I receive this error message:

"[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]"

I can connect from my own machine to the server database,i do not receive that error while running from my own machine and I'm sure my app is connected to database still receiving that error.
My .net framework is 4.5.2 and server's is 
4.7.02558.Do you think this is because of the framework?
By the way here is a snippet of code around the line causing the error:

string selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM Users AS u INNER JOIN Roles AS r ON r.ID = u.FK_Users_Role";

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    DataTable ds = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
    ///

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    //DataTable ds = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(ds);

    if (ds.Rows.Count > 0) //Check if DataTable returns data
    {
        grvUsers.DataSource = ds;
        grvUsers.DataBind();-------->error
    }

    else //else if no data returned from the DataTable then 
    {    //call the method ShowNoResultFound()
        ShowNoResultFound(ds, grvUsers);
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You check sql server connection. May be you can ping to sql server.

Comment: I am sure about my connection as I can access the DB from my own system,not the deployed app on server.and even on the deployed app the authentication phase is done ,the stored procedure is executed,showing it actually connects to DB.Just DataBind() raises the error.

Comment: Try to enable TCP/IP in SQL configuration manager and restart SQL service.

Comment: I do not have access to configuration manager, but as far as connecting to DB is concerned, my app connects to and authentication is performed, error shows up just at the specific point of "gridview1.DataBind()"